# How to export 3D files from python(pygame)

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, blender, pykinect

I have created a pygame based environment. In that I am importing a spherical ball blender based obj file. Using pykinect, I am trying to mould the object with inputs from a kinect for Xbox 360 camera.

All is working ok.

However I wish to export the end product 3D moulded object and save it in a .dae, .obj and .stl formats. Currently by recording the end coordinates of the boundary of the 3D object trying to mimic it to export, but this is a very cumbersome process.

Can someone suggest what could be done to be able to save the deformed file in the desired 3D formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are 'just' moving the locations of vertices (which is what moulding sounds like) then you can 'just' replace that block of the .obj etc file. You should be able to figure out where to cut and insert by looking at some files (I've done this with .obj but not the others so this may be harder than I suggest!)

However you should really fix the normals which you can do by taking cross products of face edges. Also uv coordinates would need fixing if you use those and that's quite a bit harder.

Comment: Currently exporting in .obj and then importing into blender and then exporting in the desired formats. Works, though will be still keen to export directly into other formats.